# Category_in return empty

Tags: query, woocommerce-offtopic, get-posts

I have the following code to obtain products within a category

```
 $product = new WC_Product($id);

 $categories = $product->get_category_ids(); //return array(21)

 $args = array();

 $args["posts_per_page"] = 10;

 $args["post_type"] = "product";

 $args["post_status"] = "publish";

 $args["category__in"] = $categories;

 $myposts = get_posts($args);
```

And **get_posts** return empty when I know there are 5 products in this category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `tax_query`, see the example in the code below:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
     'taxonomy' => 'the_taxonomy_slug', //the slug of the taxonomy you want to get
     'field' => 'term_id',
     'terms' => $categories
  ) 
);
```

See reference in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: in terms i put the ids of category o the names?

Comment: You choose, if you if you see the `field` key is set to search for the `term_id`, you can also search for the slug just change the `'field' => 'term_id'` to `'field' => 'slug'` and in `'terms'` you pass the slug of your categories

Comment: and the 'the_taxonomy_slug' should be category. right? thanksss!!

Comment: Yep, `the_taxonomy_slug` is the slug of your taxonomy, in your case is `category`